# Why does my LiveCharts piechart create 3 charts instead of 3 slices

Tags: c#, pie-chart, livecharts

I have a datatable that I want to show in a pie chart. The `Amount` would be the values and `MsgType` the lables. The chart should have 3 slices. The table looks like this:

```
MsgType    Amount
-----------------
3          4500
2          1262
1          3956
```

I have followed some examples to create a new pie series an show it in my application. The code-behind is as follows:

```
    public SeriesCollection MsgTypeDoughnut { get; set; }
    public List<int> Lables { get; set; }


    public MsgTypeProportion()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<DataMsgType> dataMsgTypes = GetMsgType();
        ChartValues<int> values = new ChartValues<int>();
        Lables = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in dataMsgTypes)
        {
            values.Add(item.Amount);
            Lables.Add(item.MsgType);
        }

        MsgTypeDoughnut = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new PieSeries
            {
                Title = "Amount",
                Values = values,
                DataLabels = true
            }
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<DataMsgType> GetMsgType()
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DataSetTableAdapters.spMessages_GetMsgTypeOverviewTableAdapter MsgTypeta = new DataSetTableAdapters.spMessages_GetMsgTypeOverviewTableAdapter();
        MsgTypeta.Fill(DS.spMessages_GetMsgTypeOverview);
        List<DataMsgType> dataMsgTypes = new List<DataMsgType>();
        foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables["spMessages_GetMsgTypeOverview"].Rows)
        {
            dataMsgTypes.Add(new DataMsgType() { MsgType = (int)row["MsgType"], Amount = (int)row["Amount"]});
        }

        return dataMsgTypes;
    }
```

But this creates 3 new piecharts and not 3 slices in 1 piechart. I have found this question [how-to-create-a-pie-chart-with-livecharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356701/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-with-livecharts) and the solution is to have multiple `PieSeries` but I can't figure out how to do that using the rows from my table.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, instead of doing:

```
foreach (var item in dataMsgTypes)
    {
        values.Add(item.Amount);
        Lables.Add(item.MsgType);
    }

    MsgTypeDoughnut = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new PieSeries
        {
            Title = "Amount",
            Values = values,
            DataLabels = true
        }
    };
```

I had to do:

```
MsgTypeDoughnut = new SeriesCollection();
foreach (var item in dataMsgTypes)
        {
            MsgTypeDoughnut.Add(new PieSeries
            {
                Title = "test",
                Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { new ObservableValue(item.Amount) },
                DataLabels = true,
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent
            });
            Lables.Add("MsgType " + (item.MsgType));
        }
```

This way the data in my table rows get added to the piechart as new slices instead of new pie charts.